# CakePHP - Controller and Model Codes

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I would like to know which portion of code / logic should be put in Controller and Model ? I am using CakePHP. Are there some guidelines to split the code between Controller and Model ?

Answer (score 1):

There are guidlines regarding Controller and Model separation.
You can find almost everything [here](https://book.cakephp.org).

**Models**

> Your model should be responsible for managing almost everything regarding your data, its validity, and its interactions, as well as the evolution of the information workflow in your domain.

**Controllers**

> Your controller should handle interpreting the request data, making sure the correct models are called, and the right response or view is rendered.